# How can I aggregate payment by week or month?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this table:

```
date        payment
----        -------
1/1/2014    2000
13/1/2014   1200
2/3/2014    1900
3/4/2014    1800
....        ....
....        ....
```

I want to calculate the weekly payment:

```
date      payment
-----     -------
week1     sum(week1)
week2     sum(week2)
....      .....
```

or monthly:

```
date      payment
-----     ------ 
month1     sum(month1) 
month2     sum(month2)
.....      .....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select extract(week from date) as week,
       sum(payment) as payments
from your_table
group by week
```

Comment: `sum` without group by?

Comment: Does mysql allow you to group by aliases?

Comment: Minor typo, `yearweak` should be `yearweek`

Comment: @HikmatSerajAl-Din That's the importance of specifying the database in your question.  Firebird doesn't have the same datetime functions, it does have `EXTRACT()`, http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-extract.html